# How to detect hardlinks over network share?

Tags: windows, nfs, server-message-block, hardlink

I swear I had this working at one point ages ago but now it's not. I have a Windows 10 machine with a Linux network share. I can create hard links on the network share just fine, but I cannot detect them. For instance, I run a file duplication program that recognizes hardlinks and won't count them as duplicates. I tried with an NFS and SMB share but neither seems to work. I also Link Shell Extension. I read that SMB 2.0 and later will not report links back, but they can be created just fine. I enabled SMB 1 and disabled SMB 2/3 but it still doesn't work. Nothing will see the hard links on NFS nor SMB. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Maybe this [one](https://winaero.com/blog/symbolic-link-in-windows-10/) can help you. Good luck with it

Comment: Interesting question but according to the answer below, the question was in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had already prioritized NFS over SMB but I guess I had forgotten the path was slightly different for NFS than for SMB. So when I thought I was accessing the NFS share, I was still on the SMB share, although I still think it should have worked since it should have been using SMB v1.0.